# Sorting an Array of Struct with type Char, qsort

Tags: arrays, c, struct, char, qsort

I am running into a zsh: segmentation fault (this error has to do with memory) I have no idea as to why it is occurring. I am trying to make a compare function for the string in my struct. I need the program to be able to sort through the strings in ascending order.

**Current Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
# define MAX 7

typedef struct{
    double price;
    char title[60];
} game;
game gArr[MAX];

game buildGame(double num, const char *title);
void printGame(game);

int compGamesByTitle(const void * a,const void * b);

int main(){
    gArr[0] = buildGame(0.01, "Minecraft");
    gArr[1] = buildGame(22.79 , "Opus Magnum");
    gArr[2] = buildGame(7.79 , "TIS-100");
    gArr[3] = buildGame(14.99 , "Trainz");
    gArr[4] = buildGame(0 , "Code Combat");
    gArr[5] = buildGame(7.79, "Lemmings Revolution");
    gArr[6] = buildGame(64.96 , "Warcraft");

    qsort(gArr,sizeof(gArr)/sizeof(gArr[0]), sizeof(gArr[0]), compGamesByTitle);
    printf("Sorted Games:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        printGame(gArr[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
int compGamesByTitle(const void *a,const void *b){
    char **aa = (char **)a;
    char **bb = (char **)b;

    return strcmp(*aa,*bb);
}

game buildGame(double num, const char *title){
    game g;
    g.price = num; strcpy(g.title, title);
    return g;
}
void printGame(game g){
    printf("Game g: %.2f, %s\n", g.price, g.title);
}
```

*I think the problem has to do with un-allocated memory but I'm not sure where or why.*

**Required Output:**
Strings in the array of structs should be sorted alphabetically (a-z) in ascending order.

Comment: You have an array of `game`, why are you casting to `char**` in your `compGamesByTitle` function?

Comment: You're right I revised the code; however, now instead of a segmentation fault, it just doesn't sort it properly. @UnholySheep

Answer (score 1):

No, your problem is not related to uninitialized memory. The comparison function passed as the fourth argument of `qsort` receives pointers to the array elements that are being compared. Since your `gArr` is an array of `game` object, but you are casting to `char**` inside the `compGamesByTitle` you end up calling `strcmp` on pointers that do not point at null-terminated byte strings, invoking *undefined behavior*.

Your comparison function should really look like this

```
int compGamesByTitle(const void *a,const void *b){
    const game *aa = a;
    const game *bb = b;

    return strcmp(aa->title, bb->title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but just som additional input to @UnholySheep answer.

The

```c
game buildGame(double num, const char *title){
    game g;
    g.price = num; strcpy(g.title, title);
    return g;
}
```

Should be more robust again long title names. Suggesting

```c
game buildGame(double num, const char *title) {
    game g;
    g.price = num;
    g.title[0] = '\0';
    strncat(g.title, title, sizeof(g.title) - 1U);
    return g;
}
```

as long as game::title remains an array.

The use of `strncat` over `strncpy` is motivated by not writing more characters than necessary.